# Dictionary Recursive indenting

Tags: python

I have the following code that tries to cover most cases of a dictionary walk, and output it as indented text (indent based on the items' nesting in the dictionary. There are two problems:

1. I think the check at the start, which caters for "raw_list", is a bit of a hack, but I cannot think of a better way
2. I cannot get the level variable to properly reflect its position

Thanks. I think the rest of the recursion is correct...

```
a = {
    "raw_list" : [1,2,3],
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : 2,
    "mydict": {
        "c":3,
        "d":4
    },
    "mydict2": {
        "c":5,
        "d":6
    },
    "list1": [
        {
            "e1":7, 
            "e2":8
        },
        {
            "e3":9, 
            "e4":10
        }
    ],
    "list2": [
        {
            "f1":11, 
            "f2":12
        }
    ]
}

def process_data(data,level):

    if not isinstance(data,list) and not isinstance(data,dict) :
        print("\t"*level + str(data))
        return

    for element, val in data.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            print("\t"*level + "DICT:" + element)
            level+=1
            process_data(val,level)
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            print("\t"*level + "LIST:" + element)
            level += 1
            for i, item in enumerate(val):
                process_data(item,level)
        else:
            print("\t"*level+element + ":" + str(val))

    level-=1

process_data(a,1)
```

Got this:

```
LIST:test
    1
    2
    3
    a:1
    b:2
    DICT:mydict
        c:3
        d:4
        DICT:mydict2
            c:5
            d:6
            LIST:list1
                e1:7
                e2:8
                e3:9
                e4:10
                LIST:list2
                    f1:11
                    f2:12
```

But want this:

```
LIST:test
    1
    2
    3
a:1
b:2
DICT:mydict
    c:3
    d:4
DICT:mydict2
    c:5
    d:6
LIST:list1
    e1:7
    e2:8
    e3:9
    e4:10
LIST:list2
    f1:11
    f2:12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing the `level` for each element in a loop. Instead, try removing `level += 1` and pass incremented `level` into the recursive call: `process_data(item, level + 1)`.

Comment: That was so simple, it's embarrassing ;)

But can you tell me regarding point 1, is there a better way?

Comment: I think your way is fine. You can simplify the check with `if not isinstance(data, (list, dict)): ...`.

Comment: Also, you could define a default for `level` (`def process_data(data, level=0):...`). So you don't need to pass it when you call the function initialy (just `process_data(a)`).

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_data(data,level):
    if not isinstance(data,list) and not isinstance(data,dict) :
        print("\t"*level + str(data))
        return

    for element, val in data.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            print("\t"*level + "DICT:" + element)
            process_data(val,level + 1)
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            print("\t"*level + "LIST:" + element)
            for i, item in enumerate(val):
                process_data(item,level + 1)
        else:
            print("\t"*level+element + ":" + str(val))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: also call function starting `0`